# Mode in method sort with Ext js 6.2.0

Tags: javascript, sorting, extjs, extjs6

Talking about method `sort([field],[direction],[mode])` with Ext js 6.2.0 . Can anyone explain to me what's the difference between  `append` , `prepend`, `replace`, `multi` on this http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-sort documentation. Mention that I don't see the difference, and there is no documentation about.

`mode :  "append" / "prepend" / "replace" / "multi" (optional)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mode parameter indicates how the collection of sorters behaves.

- `replace` - If it finds an existing sorter with the same property, replace it with the new one.
- `append` - Add to the end of the existing sorter collection.
- `prepend` - Add to the start of the existing sorter collection.
- `multi` - Will add this new sorter and purge any old sorter past the `multiSortLimit`, if it exists, else it's just the same as `append`.

Comment: thank you for replying, Is it run with remote or only local data?

Comment: Depends on the `remoteSort` config. If it's `true`, it will send a request to the server, if not it will sort the local data.

Answer (score 0):

This is an `Ext.data.Store` method. When you call it, you explicitly sort the elements of the store. The resulting sorted list can:

- "replace" the original list in the store
- "append"ed at the end of the original list
- "prepend"ed at the beginning of the list
- "multi"?????

Comment: The `mode` indicates how the sorters behave, not the data in the list.